# Sequence of cases

Tags: accusative

When I studied German before the cases were listed as Nominativ, Genitiv, Dativ and Akkusativ. Now the sequence is changed so that Akkusativ is second! This makes it more difficult to "relearn" German as all the endings have a changed order. Why has this changed?